# wireshark: convert data from dump to a text file using filters

Tags: filter, output, wireshark, dump, packet

Tell me how to convert (using Wireshark utilities) the dump, received by Wireshark into a text file (for example, csv file), that will contain only (using filters):

- time of package receipt
- package size
- protocol
- source address
- destination address

May be use tshark.exe, but how?

Answer (score 0):

solved

```
tshark.exe -r my.dump -T fields -e frame.time_relative -e frame.time_delta -e frame.len -e eth.src -e eth.dst -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e ip.proto -E header=y -E separator=; -E occurrence=f > results.csv
```

for example